# Submanifold proof

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

**Problem:** If there is some subset defined on $\Lambda \times \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\Lambda$ is a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ then the subset $\Psi= \{(a,ka)\in \Lambda \times \mathbb{R}^3:k\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a sub-manifold of $\Lambda \times \mathbb{R}^3.$

So this is the problem I am stuck with at the moment, I know that if one is a submanifold of another, then I have to show that the map $I$ is an injection where:

$I:\Psi \rightarrow \Lambda \times \mathbb{R}^3$

I am really stuck with this problem as I am not yet experienced with manifolds, can anyone show me how to do this so I can get the idea of how to do these problems?

**EDIT:** $(0,0,0)\notin \Lambda$

Comment: That the map $I$ is an injection is trivial, as $\Psi$ is a subset. The thing you need to check is that the subset is an actual manifold. The direct way would look something like this: Pick a coordinate chart of $\Lambda$ and try to use this to construct a coordinate chart of $\Psi$. (Hint: be careful with the dimensions) From there you then need to show that all of $\Psi$ is covered by such charts and that changing from one to the other is a smooth map.

Comment: For instance, if I decided to use the chart $F:U \rightarrow \Lambda$ as $F(u_1,u_2,u_3)=a$ on $\Lambda$, then is it correct to say that we have an induced local parametrizaton of $\Psi$ as $F^*(u_1,u_2.u_3)=(a,ak)?$

Comment: Roughly yes, however the induced local parametrisation would be $F^*: U\times \mathbb{R} \to \Lambda \times \mathbb{R}^3, (u_1,u_2,u_3,k) \mapsto (F(u),F(u)k)$ as $\Psi$ is a 4-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Then from here, we have to show that there exists some $(\overline{F})^{-1}(I(F^*(u_1,u_2,u_3,k)))$ such that it is smooth. Now we have found $F^*$, so how to find the remaining $(\overline{F})^{-1}?$. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Shouldn't $\Psi$ be 6 dimensional? Since $\Lambda$ is 3 and $\mathbb{R}^3$ is also 3?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, please ignore the previous remark about dimensions. $\Psi$ is a 3-dimensional submanifold in 6-dimensional space. 2 of those dimensions are from $\Lambda$ (which is a regular surface, thus 2-dimensional) and the last one we get through the choice of k. Thus the parametrisation  should only involve $u_1$ and $u_2$. Anyway, you might want to read up a bit more on coordinate charts and atlases, as there seems to be still some confusion.

Comment: ok, now I have another question, why does a regular surface have $n-1 $ number of dimensions? Why cant it have $3$ dimensions? I dont see why $\Lambda$ only makes up 2 dimensions, because it may be a three dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^3?$

Comment: This is just a definition. A regular surface is always a 2-dimensional manifold, while a regular hypersurface is always $n-1$-dimensional. (If $n$ is the dimension of the surrounding space) For all other cases one just speaks of a $k$-dimensional manifold. Incidentally $3$-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are just open subsets.

Comment: Ok I will take this definition for granted, but $(a,ka$), $a$ is 2-dimensional, but $ka$ how is this 1 dimensional?

Comment: The freedom of choice of $a$ is already "spent" with the other two dimensions, so this just leaves you to choose $k$, which is one real variable, thus one dimension. Of course this is just intuition, however it will be one of the key ideas in any proof.

Comment: Ok thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: the set $f^{-1}(0) \subseteq \Lambda\times\mathbb{R}^3$ for a smooth function $f:\Lambda\times\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth manifold, take e.g. $f: (x,y) \mapsto kx-y$

Comment: I forgot to mention that $(0,0,0) \notin \Lambda$, thank you for the help, but I really cant do much with what you gave me...